# Animate svg lines

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have an SVG file with lines in it. Now I would like the line on the left to animate from right to left (one time), and the line on the right to animate from left to right (one time).

I have made an example, but you can see that this does not work well yet.

Can someone please help me with this?

Here is an example I made:

```js
var paths = document.querySelectorAll('.st3');
[].forEach.call(paths, function(path) {
  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
  path.getBoundingClientRect();
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 1.8s ease-in-out';
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
})
```

```css
.st3 {
  fill: #EA1140;
  stroke: #333;
  animation: fill 0.95s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1.75s;
}

@keyframes fill {
  from {
    fill: #EA1140;
  }
  to {
    fill: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1355 40" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1355 40;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
      .st0{fill:#5D5D5D;}
  </style>
  <rect x="685" y="19.5" class="st0 st3" width="670" height="1"/>
  <rect x="684" class="st0" width="1" height="40"/>
  <rect y="19.5" class="st0 st3" width="668.5" height="1"/>
  <rect x="668.5" y="7" class="st0" width="4" height="26"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Your code is working but you can not see it. The line animation is supposed to animate the stroke. You don't have a stroke, instead you have a fill. You don't have a line, you have rectangles with a very small height. Use a <line> or a <path> element instead